# Outlook 2010 on Windows XP repeatedly asks for exchange credentials

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2013

We have a Windows XP machine that we can't upgrade *yet* to Windows 7/8.  It's running Outlook 2010.  It is connected to a web-based hosted Exchange 2013 provider.

Many repeated times per day, a Microsoft Exchange dialog box pops up ([screenshot](http://snag.gy/WStE3.jpg)) showing the Exchange Server and the Mailbox (with the textboxes disabled and Check Name button greyed out).

We have to click OK to continue, and the box continues to appear.

Our hosted Exchange provider says it's a problem with XP and/or Office 2010.  However, this seems to be a sporadic issue - not always happens.

We will be hopefully upgrading this machine to 7 or 8 soon, when we can get approval, but for now it needs to stay at XP.  Does anyone know how to suppress this message while maintaining connectivity to the hosted Exchange mailbox?

Thanks!

Comment: It's odd that pictured dialog would show up, for sure. At what point does it ask for credentials?

Comment: To clarify, this is the only dialog that appears.  I assumed it was asking for credentials, but the input boxes are disabled.